# Unrecognized selector Error when saving an image using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum

Tags: iphone, ios, uigesturerecognizer, uiactionsheet, unrecognized-selector

A UILongPressGestureRecognizer is added to my imageView with action handleLongPressOnPhotos. The most related codes is as following:

```
- (IBAction)handleLongPressOnPhotos:(UIImageView *)sender{
self.imageWillBeSaved = sender;
UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Save the photo" otherButtonTitles: @"Go to the Original photo", nil];
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;
[actionSheet showInView:self.view]; 
[actionSheet release];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.imageWillBeSaved.image, self, @selector(image: didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

        break;

    default:
        break;
}

}

- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
{
if (error != NULL)
{
    // handle error
}
else 
{
    // handle ok status
}
}
```

When the "save the photo" button on the action sheet is clicked, an error message as:**-[UILongPressGestureRecognizer image]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x21c2a0**
Any problem in the code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: where you have added UILongPressGestureRecognizer? Add that code as well.

Comment: plz check for the following answers, problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sender is obviously the UILongPressGestureRecognizer.

Methods that fire when a gesture recognizer is triggered should look like this

```
- (void)nameOfMethodHere:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
```

The argument is the recognizer, not the image view. If the recognizer is only attached to one view you get it via the `view` property. Otherwise you can get the location of the long tap and hit test to get the view.

Comment: I can save the image now, but why the action sheet will not be dismissed after i click the "save the photo" button? If i click the button again, the action sheet dismissed and the photo saved twice.

Comment: Saving the image may take a second. Do you get the callback if you wait? Maybe you should dismiss the actionSheet right away (in actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:) and wait for the callback. IF there is an error then you present it, if not the user will assume that everything went ok.

Comment: It is not because of the delay. I post a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511047/can-not-dismiss-an-action-sheet-here  , plz check

Answer (score 5):

Just replace the top two lines..

```
- (IBAction)handleLongPressOnPhotos:(UIImageView *)sender{
self.imageWillBeSaved = sender;
```

with..

```
- (IBAction)handleLongPressOnPhotos:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender{
self.imageWillBeSaved = sender.view;
```

and this should work... the reason why this is happening is very well explained by David.

Comment: Yes, it works, but I run into another problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10511047/can-not-dismiss-an-action-sheet-here

Answer (score 2):

This is for `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
[YOURVIEW addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
[longPress release];
```

This is Selector for `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, The problem in your code is that, you are passing `UIImageView` as argument in Selector of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` just edit that with this..

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender 
{ 
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) 
    {
         //YOUR CODE
    }
}
```